# How to save tweeter data in json file?

Tags: python, json, pandas, tweets, twython

I am scraping the data from tweeter using Twython. I could get this done successfully. However, for further data manipulation, I need to save the tweeter data to JSON or any other format that can be opened with pandas.

I want to include every single column from the scraping result, including language location, retweets and so on. I know how to do this for a few columns, but I could not find the information about how to include all of them.

```
import json
credentials = {}
credentials['CONSUMER_KEY'] = '...'
credentials['CONSUMER_SECRET'] = '...'
credentials['ACCESS_TOKEN'] = '...'
credentials['ACCESS_SECRET'] = '...'

# Save the credentials object to file
with open("twitter_credentials.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(credentials, file)

# Import the Twython class
from twython import Twython
import json

# Load credentials from json file
with open("twitter_credentials.json", "r") as file:
    creds = json.load(file)

# Instantiate an object
python_tweets = Twython(creds['CONSUMER_KEY'], creds['CONSUMER_SECRET'])

python_tweets.search(q='#python', result_type='popular',count=5)

OUTPUT:
{'statuses': [{'created_at': 'Mon Dec 14 04:05:03 +0000 2020',
   'id': 1338334158205169664,
   'id_str': '1338334158205169664',
   'text': '  Hmmm...this looks right, doesn’t it? We’ll give you a hint - the result is meant to be 36!\n\nCan you find the err… ',
   'truncated': True,
   'entities': {'hashtags': [],
    'symbols': [],
    'user_mentions': [],
    'urls': [{'url': '',
      'expanded_url': '',
      'display_url': 'twitter.com/i/web/status/1…',
      'indices': [117, 140]}]},
   'metadata': {'result_type': 'popular', 'iso_language_code': 'en'},
   'source': '<a href=">',
   'in_reply_to_status_id': None,
   'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None,
   'in_reply_to_user_id': None,
   'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None,
   
and so on
```

My question is: how can I save the data I got from tweeter into json format so I can open it lately with pandas. I basically just want to open it with pandas somehow.

I have tried the following codes:

```
data= {}
data[python_tweets.search(q='#python', result_type='popular',count=5)]
with open("twitter_new.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(data, file)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'


data=python_tweets.search(q='#python', result_type='popular',count=5)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

Comment: what is your data? The OUTPUT dictionary?

Comment: I am scrappinging the data from the tweeter. And in the output the information of the tweet that has a specific hashtag. I want to make a table out of it

Comment: alwys put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you didn't snow FULL error message which should show which line makes problem. As for me problem is not to save data but `data[python_tweets.search...]`. In your code `data` is a dictionary and it needs `data[key] = value` but you use `python_tweets.search(...)` as `key` (but it should be used as `value`) and it makes problem. Maybe you should assign `data = python_tweets.search(...)`

Comment: if you want to save in JSON then you should use `data = python_tweets.search(...)` before `json.dump(data, ...)`. But next question is if dataframe will know how to load JSON with nested element. `Dataframe` works with tables (rows, columns) and maybe you should first convert your tweech to somethink more similar to table. OR maybe you should save only `data['statuses']` which is more similar to table.

Answer (score 0):

To save results from `search()` you should simply assing to variable `data = ...` and save it

```
data = client.search(q='#python', result_type='popular', count=5)

with open('tweets_python.json', 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(data, fh)
```

But this JSON has complex structure - it has two different subdictionares `data['statuses']` and `data['search_metadata']` which can't be converted together to one `DataFrame`. But probably you need only values from `data['statuses']` (even without saving in file)

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(data['statuses'])
 print(df)
```

Result:

```
                       created_at                   id               id_str  ... retweeted  possibly_sensitive lang
0  Sun Dec 20 15:14:21 +0000 2020  1340676922230136833  1340676922230136833  ...     False               False   en
1  Sun Dec 20 04:12:58 +0000 2020  1340510479861616643  1340510479861616643  ...     False               False   en
2  Sun Dec 20 15:06:34 +0000 2020  1340674963452391426  1340674963452391426  ...     False               False   en
3  Mon Dec 14 04:05:03 +0000 2020  1338334158205169664  1338334158205169664  ...     False               False   en
4  Mon Dec 14 21:38:14 +0000 2020  1338599202125803521  1338599202125803521  ...     False               False   en
```

---

Minimal working code which I used to test it

```
from twython import Twython
import json
import pandas as pd

# --- credentials ---

with open("twitter_credentials.json", "r") as file:
    creds = json.load(file)
CONSUMER_KEY    = creds['CONSUMER_KEY']
CONSUMER_SECRET = creds['CONSUMER_SECRET']

#import os
#CONSUMER_KEY    = os.getenv('TWITTER_KEY')
#CONSUMER_SECRET = os.getenv('TWITTER_SECRET')

# --- main ---

client = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

data = client.search(q='#python', result_type='popular', count=5)

#print(data.keys())  # 'statuses', 'search_metadata'

# save in JSON

with open('tweets_python.json', 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(data, fh)

# use directly with pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(data['statuses'])

print(df)
```

---

**BTW:**

Your dictionary `data = {}` could be useful if you would like to keep many results

```
data = {}

data['python'] = client.search(q='#python', ...)
data['php']    = client.search(q='#php', ...)
data['java']   = client.search(q='#java', ...)
```

and save it in separated `JSON` files

```
for key, value in data.items():
    filename = f'tweets_{key}.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as fh:
        json.dump(value, fh)
```

or open in separated `DataFrames`

```
all_dfs = {}

for key, value in data.items():
    all_dfs[key] = pd.DataFrame(value['statuses'])

for key, df in all_dfs.items():
    print('dataframe for:', key)
    print(df)
```

---

Minimal working code which I used to test it

```
from twython import Twython
import json
import pandas as pd

# --- credentials ---

with open("twitter_credentials.json", "r") as file:
    creds = json.load(file)
CONSUMER_KEY    = creds['CONSUMER_KEY']
CONSUMER_SECRET = creds['CONSUMER_SECRET']

#import os
#CONSUMER_KEY    = os.getenv('TWITTER_KEY')
#CONSUMER_SECRET = os.getenv('TWITTER_SECRET')

# --- main ---

client = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

data = {}

data['python'] = client.search(q='#python', result_type='popular', count=5)
data['php']    = client.search(q='#php', result_type='popular', count=5)
data['java']   = client.search(q='#java', result_type='popular', count=5)

# save in JSON

for key, value in data.items():
    filename = f'tweets_{key}.json'
    print('saving', filename)

    with open(filename, 'w') as fh:
        json.dump(value, fh)

# use directly with pandas

all_dfs = {}

for key, value in data.items():
    all_dfs[key] = pd.DataFrame(value['statuses'])

for key, df in all_dfs.items():
    print('dataframe for:', key)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It worked perfectly :)

Comment: Also when I use the code data = python_tweets.search(q='#blacklivesmatter', result_type='mixed', count=10000) I get only 100 tweets added to file. Do you know how can I get 10k different tweets and save them in one json file?

Comment: first check what gives `len(data)` - maybe server gives only 100 tweets. You should also check how many tweets you can get directly on Twitter. OR maybe twitter gives more only if you pay for this.

Comment: official Twitter API documentation: in [Parameters](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) it shows that it gives only 100 values. You would have to try to use parameters `until`, `since_id`, `max_id` to get older values - if you will change date or ID then you can get older and older values.

Comment: I tried to use `search` with `max_id` but it didn't work - it always gives me the same tweets. I had no problem with `max_id` in module `tweepy`. But finally in documentation I found [Search Generator](https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/advanced_usage.html#search-generator) which probably can resolve all problems.